# read specific field values from a .csv file from korn script

Tags: unix

how to read specific field values from a .csv file using korn script.

Say the input was as follows:

```
First_name      lastname    dept    collge
Ravi            shangar     csc xxx
ram             Devi        csc zzz
raj                 shangar         csc     yyy
```

so I need to extract distinct lastname values.Any suggestions?

Comment: Please let us know what you have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to get the second column as follows:

```
$ awk '{print $2}' file
lastname
shangar
Devi
```

Awk uses a whitespace delimiter by default, but you can change it if necessary using the `-F` option.

Comment: The claimed output is different from what you'd actually get. That will print the same last name twice if it appears twice in the input, and also prints the heading.  Maybe: `awk 'NR==1 { next } { if (count[$2]++ == 0) print $2 }' file`?  If the heading is wanted, omit the `NR==1 { next }` part.

Comment: The question has been updated since my answer. The first version, did not ask for "distinct lastnames".